# How do hackers fund their Ethereum gas for attacking contracts?

Tags: attacks, hack

I was wondering how do hackers fund their Ethereum balances privately to further execute attacks? What protocols do they usually use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution myself.

Most of them use Tornado cash and other mixers to privately transfer funds from one wallet to another.